# Error in twFromJSON(out) - R twitteR package

Tags: json, r, twitter

I have searched extensively online but am still unable to find a work-around for the following error whilst using the 'twitteR' package in R:

```
"Error in twFromJSON(out) : 
Error: Malformed response from server, was not JSON.
The most likely cause of this error is Twitter returning a character which
can't be properly parsed by R. Generally the only remedy is to wait long
enough for the offending character to disappear from searches (e.g. if
using searchTwitter())."
```

It comes after running the following code:

```
# Clear the previously used libraries
rm(list=ls())

#Set Working Directory
setwd("C:/Users/toshiba/Google Drive/Programming/Projects/HDS/Shiny/Twitter")

#Load Libraries
library (twitteR)
library (RJSONIO)
library (dismo)
library (maps)
library (ggplot2)
library (XML)
load("twitteR_credentials")
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
##############################Start App########################################
start_date = '2014-10-10'
end_date = toString(as.Date(start_date)+1)

#Search for tweets containing ebola - only goes back 8 days including today
ebolaTweets <- searchTwitter("ebola", 
                             n = 1250,
                             since=start_date,
                             until=end_date,
                             cainfo="cacert.pem")
tweetFrame <- twListToDF(ebolaTweets) # convert to dataframe
```

Is it not possible to somehow skip the offending tweet instead of breaking the loop?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [current version of `twitteR` (1.1.8) on Github](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) (which handles authentication much more simply), I have no problems.

```
library(devtools)
install_github('twitteR', 'geoffjentry')

library (twitteR)
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key='blah', consumer_secret='blah', 
                    access_token='blah', access_secret='blah')
# get keys and tokens from apps.twitter.com

start.date <- '2014-10-10'
end.date <- as.character(as.Date(start_date) + 1)
ebolaTweets <- searchTwitter('ebola', 1250, since=start.date, until=end.date)
ebola <- twListToDF(ebolaTweets)

head(ebola)
#                                                                                                                                           text
# 1                                                         RT @ChillVibessonly: Ebola: I'm in the US broom broom\n\nAmerica: Get out me country
# 2 RT @RubenSanchezTW: #Alucinante TVE usa imágenes de un hospital alemán para ilustrar una info sobre el Carlos III http://t.co/5f5okmsjar ht…
# 3                                                                                          RT @DanLpda: Dejen de hablar del Ébola, me da miedo
# 4     Realiza Colombia estudios a 3 viajeros por temor a ébola: Pese a no presentar síntomas del virus los pasajeros... http://t.co/C5iJmgoQkI
# 5                                                                                                           Que es eso del ebola? Voy a llorar
# 6                                                                            RT @MicaMamonde: ebola no te tenemos miedo http://t.co/osgLmAmFnP
#   favorited favoriteCount replyToSN             created truncated replyToSID                 id replyToUID
# 1     FALSE             0      <NA> 2014-10-10 23:59:59     FALSE       <NA> 520725464223326209       <NA>
# 2     FALSE             0      <NA> 2014-10-10 23:59:59     FALSE       <NA> 520725464185581568       <NA>
# 3     FALSE             0      <NA> 2014-10-10 23:59:59     FALSE       <NA> 520725463304785921       <NA>
# 4     FALSE             0      <NA> 2014-10-10 23:59:59     FALSE       <NA> 520725463270821889       <NA>
# 5     FALSE             1      <NA> 2014-10-10 23:59:59     FALSE       <NA> 520725463120244737       <NA>
# 6     FALSE             0      <NA> 2014-10-10 23:59:59     FALSE       <NA> 520725463044734976       <NA>
#                                                                           statusSource      screenName retweetCount
# 1 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>    JaMeseKisses          684
# 2 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>   patillagrande         2059
# 3                   <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a> AriiFranciscovi            2
# 4                      <a href="http://twitterfeed.com" rel="nofollow">twitterfeed</a>         ColnRos            0
# 5   <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>     ZoeVignieri            0
# 6                   <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a> felicitasalbano           10
#   isRetweet retweeted longitude latitude
# 1      TRUE     FALSE      <NA>     <NA>
# 2      TRUE     FALSE      <NA>     <NA>
# 3      TRUE     FALSE      <NA>     <NA>
# 4     FALSE     FALSE      <NA>     <NA>
# 5     FALSE     FALSE      <NA>     <NA>
# 6      TRUE     FALSE      <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: Running it now on a large number of tweets, and it has not crashed yet! Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm it worked on 50.000 tweets without crashing!

Comment: @RalphM I am trying to retrieve 50,000 tweets and I got a waring like : "Rate limited .... blocking for a minute and retrying up to 119 times ..." Any idea what this is ?